# How get page with youtube channel's videos using google-api-client or yt gem?

Tags: ruby, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-client, google-api-ruby-client

**Intro**

Hi all! I am developing rails app, which shows table with videos from youtube channel. I may use `google-api-client` or `yt` gem.

**Problem**

User's channel may contain more then 100 videos, so it creates delays and O need pagination. I know that youtube API supports pagination by passing `maxResults` and `page_token` parameters with requests. But how can I do it using `google-api-client` gem?

**Details**

So, here's my code:

```
@client = Google::Client::Youtube.new(
  key:                 APP_CONFIG[:youtube_auth_token],
  application_name:    APP_CONFIG[:youtube_app_name], 
  application_version: APP_CONFIG[:youtube_app_version],
  authorization:       nil
)
some_channel = @client.channels.first

some_channel.videos 
#=> returns me a list of videos, sometimes it's ~500 videos

some_channel.videos(
  page: 1, 
  offset: 25, 
  videos_on_page: 212,
  how_can_do_it: "???"
)
```

Or with `yt`:

```
channel    = Yt::Channel.new id: 'WERTYUGHgfhg'
all_videos = channel.videos

page_my_page_token = channel.videos(page_token) 

page_my_page_token # => ???
```

**Question**

How to get first page with first 5 videos? than next page? and how check that page is last?

Many thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend checking out the [code samples](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/ruby) and [documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/google/google-api-ruby-client/Google/Apis/YoutubeV3) if you haven't done so already.

Comment: @not_a_bot I have read this documentation, and know about 'google page tokens'... I am asking about possibility to get paginated data using ruby gems like 'yt' or 'google-api-client'. The problem is that I am using 'yt' gem, and trying to show table with channel videos on page. Sometimes channel have ~3500 videos and requests/response time take more than 10sec :( that's why I search for pagination - make a few requests via ajax and make some infinity scroll.

Comment: There's a pagination example using google-api-client for Ruby here: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/ruby/guide/pagination